# Ubuntu Gnome 3 and Windwos FAIL BOOT

Tags: boot, gnome, windows, usb, format

I have a strange issue:

I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.10 Gnome edition on a usb and every time I wanted to use this Ubuntu to plug my usb into my laptop and boot the usb enjoy the cool OS. I made a usb with the distro and 10gb of perserve space. Plug, boot, on the install screen format and install. Gnome started everything is OK.

After that I wanted to log on my main OS that is Win7. Shutdown the whole laptop. Unplug the usb and start the computer. But it booted automatically (without asking me and I dont know how when the usb is not connected) Ubuntu Gnome3...

I'm starting to think that I made the huge mistake to format my whole harddrive and not to use the usb as a portable OS :X

I'm very new to this community and to Ubuntu/Linux = noob, so I will appriciate friendly comments and not too much Linux jargon(terminologie).

First thing is how can I see my whole hard disk and all installed OS?
Second is there a way to revert the process :D ?
Third... I think that whatever happens I will try this (the portable ubuntu OS) one more time so maybe I need a complete/newb guide for someone like me.
Fourth.. I dont know yet but I'm sure that there are more questions that are waiting to be invoked. :D

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question consists of several parts and might be best dealt with in pieces. I suggest you edit your question to restrict it to smaller tractable parts and open more questions as they come up. In your case, you need to find out first what happened to your laptop disk.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately do not have good news. You put the live image of Ubuntu Gnome on your USB key. If you just wanted to use it from the USB your best option would have been to 'Try out Ubuntu Gnome'. However by choosing to Format and install, you did not format your USB key but your entire computer. As the warning indicated, that means you wiped out everything off of your computer completely.

For your questions:
1) Open up the Files program to see everything on your computer (looks like a little filing cabinet).

2) No, you have wiped your hard-drive and put the Ubuntu Gnome operating system on it instead.

3) No need to try the portable version at this point, it's installed completely on your computer, might as well enjoy it :)

4) One option that may be available is to re-install your Windows 7 and then use a live image on a USB key or to create a 'dual boot' system in which you are given a choice of Windows or Ubuntu at start-up. However this will not restore your old windows 7 installation and will not restore any files or data you had previously.